# SQL: Joining 3 tables to generate report dashboard

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to join 3 different tables that holds my test execution results as "PASS", "FAIL" and "SKIP". There are 2 common properties in these 3 tables on the basis of which I need to club my result i.e. "BUILD_NUMBER" and "COMPONENT".

Tried several approach but does not get the desired result.

Best result reached so far.
[image: Best Output Received!!]

Sample query:

```
select test_execution.COMPONENT, test_execution.BUILD_NUMBER, 
count(test_execution.TEST_STATUS) as PASS from (test_execution 
INNER JOIN test_execution_fail ON
test_execution.BUILD_NUMBER = test_execution_fail.BUILD_NUMBER) group by 
COMPONENT,BUILD_NUMBER;
```

My tables look like below:

```
CREATE TABLE test_execution_skip (
BUILD_NUMBER int,
TEST_NAME varchar(255),
TEST_CLASS varchar(255),
COMPONENT varchar(255),
TEST_STATUS varchar(255)
```

);

Other two tables are exactly same with **test_execution** and **test_execution_fail** as their names.

test_execution table holds 3 records(all pass values), test_execution_fail table holds 2 records (all fail values) and test_execution_skip table holds 1 record(skip value).

I want to populate data that will show me BUILD_NUMBER, COMPONENT, TOTAL, PASS, FAIL, SKIP as records where TOTAL, PASS, FAIL and SKIP will show the respectives counts.

Any help is appreciated here.

Comment: `MySQL` <> `SQL Server`. Please update the tag accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question but you could try something like this

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT * FROM test_execution 
union
SELECT * FROM test_execution_fail
UNION
SELECT * FROM test_execution_skip 
)


SELECT t.*,  (SKIP + FAIL + PASS) AS TOTAL  FROM (
select
      COMPONENT,
      BUILD_NUMBER,
      SUM(IF(TEST_STATUS = 'skip', 1, 0 )) as SKIP, 
      SUM(IF(TEST_STATUS = 'fail', 1, 0 )) as FAIL, 
      SUM(IF(TEST_STATUS = 'pass', 1, 0 )) as PASS
      FROM cte
group by COMPONENT,BUILD_NUMBER
)t
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13d2a8cd6db001e07bd6ec2913ace097)

Comment: This really helps. Infact I don't need to have 3 different table. Single table can give me the counts as you suggested above. Thanks !!!